# Rails app not working after initial deploy using capistrano (puma.sock failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I am getting the following errors in nginx.error.log file:

> 2017/01/19 23:51:57 [crit] 809#809: *1 connect() to
>   unix:///home/deploy/Production01/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/Production01-puma.sock
>   failed (2: No such file or
>   home/deploy/Production01/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/Production01-puma.sock:/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi",
>   host: "185.123.188.98", referrer: "1" 2017/01/19 23:51:57 [info]
>   809#809: *1 client 217.118.84.185 closed keepalive connection

and in the puma.log I have:

> === puma startup: 2017-01-19 23:53:00 +0200 ===
>   * Listening on unix:///home/deploy/apps/Production01/shared/tmp/sockets/Production01-puma.sock

1. [deploy.rb](https://github.com/gotqn/Production01/blob/master/config/deploy.rb)
2. [puma.rb](https://github.com/gotqn/Production01/blob/master/config/puma.rb)
3. [nginx.conf](https://github.com/gotqn/Production01/blob/master/config/nginx.conf)

I am using capistrano and everything is deployed correctly. On my local machine the demo project is working fine.

This is my first deploy and I guess I have not do something correctly in the config files.

Could you advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to symlink your nginx files.

Try this on your server

```
cd ~

sudo ln -nfs home/deploy/Production01/appname/current/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/appname

sudo ln -nfs /etc/nginx/sites-available/appname /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

sudo service nginx restart
```